# elastic search "word" data type : mapping is not proper

Tags: elasticsearch

I am newbie in elastic search and I have been experimenting with it from the past few days. I am not able to do proper mapping as all the  data types, I mentioned in the mapping are being mapped to the type "word" instead of the respective types. Here is the mapping I have done

```
POST my_index
{
 "settings" : {
 "analysis" : {
 "analyzer" : {
    "lowercase_analyzer" : {
      "type" : "custom",
      "tokenizer" : "keyword",
      "filter" : ["lowercase"]
    }
   }
 }
},
"mappings" : {
 "my_type" : {
  "properties" : {
    "name" : {"type" : "string" ,"index" : "not_analyzed"   },
    "field0" : {
      "properties" : {
        "field1" : {"type" : "boolean" },
        "field2" : {"type" : "string" },
        "field3" : {"type" : "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSSSSS" }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

To test the mapping, I am using "_analyze" api as follows

```
GET my_index/_analyze
{
   "field" : "name",
   "text" : "10.90.99.6"
}
```

which gives me the following result

```
{
 "tokens": [
 {
   "token": "10.90.99.6",
  "start_offset": 0,
  "end_offset": 10,
  "type": "word",
  "position": 0
}
] 
}
```

I am expecting the "type" in the result to be "string". However I could not understand why it is returning of type "word". Also the same is happening with other fields as well when I post the data of type boolean or time stamp in the nested fields using _analyze api.

```
GET my_index/_analyze
{
 "field" : "field0.field1",
 "text" : "true"
}
```

Result

```
 {
   "tokens": [
  {
    "token": "true",
    "start_offset": 0,
    "end_offset": 4,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 0
   }
  ]
 }
```

Where am I doing wrong in my mapping.

Also, there is no such "word" data type in [elastic search reference api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error at all, you did it right. The concept of `type` in the mapping and the concept of `type` in the `_analyze` API is different.

The `_analyze` API  will simply return all tokens that are present in the field you're analyzing and each of those tokens is typed "word". That comes from the Lucene [`TypeAttribute`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/5.2.1/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/TypeAttribute.java/) class and as you can see there's only one default value `"word"`